# Cannot assign to property 'tabBarController' is a get-only property

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, swift2

I have declared a global variable:

```
var tabBarController: UITabBarController?
```

Now when I try to assign to this global variable inside my `UITabBarController` class:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        tabBarController = self
}
```

I receive this error:

> Cannot assign to property 'tabBarController' is a get-only property

Why am I getting this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your own property collides with an already existing property of the same name that every `UIViewController` has:

> [tabBarController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621169-tabbarcontroller) - The nearest ancestor in the view controller hierarchy that is a tab bar controller.

```
var tabBarController: UITabBarController? { get }
```

As you can clearly see that property is `get`-only.

If you choose a different name for that property you will be fine. Or you configure all the connections in the interface builder beforehand.

Comment: you are a Goddamn genius!